# Does an heavy propeller aircraft (CS-25) have the Blu Line (Vyse) displayed on ASI?

Tags: easa-regulations, aircraft-certification, propeller-aircraft

Does a propeller aircraft that is categorized as CS-25 (EASA Regulation) have the Blue Line (Vyse) mandatory displyed on ASI? 
I know that would be the case for lighter aircraft (Less than 19000 lbs /8600kg), but my question is related for heavy aircraft (Dash8 example).

Answer (score 3):

**No**, larger aircraft typically don't have such speeds shown on the ASI because they **vary significantly with weight**. See also [Why don't Transport Category aircraft have a listed Vy?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27488/why-dont-transport-category-aircraft-have-a-listed-vy).

For the Dash-8 Q400 for example, the $V_{\text{y}_\text{SE}}$ speed is called $V_\text{CLIMB}$:

> VCLIMB – Single-engine best rate-of-climb speed.

The following table shows the values for $V_\text{CLIMB}$ as a function of weight:

```
+-----------+--------+
|  Weight   | VCLIMB |
+-----------+--------+
| 18.000 kg | 130 kt |
| 20.000 kg | 131 kt |
| 22.000 kg | 137 kt |
| 24.000 kg | 143 kt |
| 26.000 kg | 148 kt |
| 28.000 kg | 154 kt |
| 29.000 kg | 158 kt |
+-----------+--------+
```

As you can see, the values vary too much to show a single blue line on the ASI.

This does not mean that the speed cannot be displayed at all. The Dash-8 Q400 has a Primary Flight Display (PFD) and can show up to 5 speed markers on the speed tape ($V_1$, $V_\text{R}$, $V_2$ and two more called #1 and #2, typically used for $V_\text{FRI}$ and $V_\text{CLIMB}$ respectively during takeoff and initial climb).

[image: Q400 Speed Bugs]
<sup>([Dash-8 Q400 FCOM - Indicating and Recording Systems](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/Q400-Indicating_and_Recording_Systems.html))</sup>

The resulting markers on the PFD look like this:

[image: Q400 PFD]
<sup>([Dash-8 Q400 FCOM - Indicating and Recording Systems](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/Q400-Indicating_and_Recording_Systems.html))</sup>

The electronic standby instrument does not show these markers.